# Using regex/preg_match() to check if a set of coordinates in decimal degrees is valid

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, validation

I've learnt a bit of basic regex to wet my feet, but it's all still a bit too complicated for me. I need to take a set of user-inputted coordinates in decimal degrees (example):

```
$latitude = -42.323432
$longitude = 176.232123
```

and check whether they're valid using the `preg_match()` function in PHP. Seems simple, but I can't write the regular expression for the life of me that would ensure that no bad data gets through. I'll check the northing and easting separate of each other so this `preg_match()` will be iterated through twice using a `foreach` loop.

I think I've figured out all the necessary conditions:

- The first character can either be a minus, a plus, or a number. The minuses and pluses are optional.
- The total count of numbers before the decimal point can be 1 to 3, but not 0 or above 3.
- Therefore there must be a decimal point in either the second place, or the fourth place. (2.2332, -123.422)
- There must be at EXACTLY one decimal point in the whole string, there can be 0 OR 1 minuses or pluses in the whole string.
- I want at least 3 decimal places of precision AFTER the decimal point. There is no maximum limit (I'll simply round it to 6 dp myself)
- If there are any characters besides numbers, a decimal point, and an optional plus and minus, reject it.

After this though, I'm stuck! Any help would be appreciated in writing the regex expression. Thanks...

Comment: Show the regex you've got until now.

Comment: I... I don't have any. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: You could go for [is_numeric](http://php.net/is_numeric)

Comment: @Dale, plus a boundary check, I'd say.

Comment: @Dale, I considered that, but since it allows octal values, that would let in an 'x' character, not to mention the 'e' exponential character, so it's too vague for what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a stab at it:

```
  /^[+\-]?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{3,}\z/
```

Broken down:

```
  ^                 - start of string
  [+\-]?            - zero or one from set of `+` and `-`
  [0-9]{1,3}        - 1 to 3 digits
  \.                - decimal point
  [0-9]{3,}         - 3 or more digits
  \z                - end of string
```

(note, this is untested ;))

Comment: I managed to write something similar to this too... but then I wondered what happens if I append a letter to the start or end of the string? i.e. z-122.32344zz? Doesn't `preg_match()` work a la `preg_match(needle, haystack);`? So my example would be considered okay, even though it really isn't?

Comment: @Antilogical, you should anchor the expression with `^` and `\z` for that. Eg: `/^[+-]?\d{1,3}\.\d{3,}\z/`

Comment: @Antilogical added `^` and `$` as start and end of string.

Comment: @Qtax, neat, but why is the middle of your expression significantly different from Bart's?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, thank you... one more thing, what do the forward slashes at the start and end of the expression indicate?

Comment: @Antilogical they are expression delimiters, they tell the parser when the expresssion starts and ends. You can add additional options after it. Read more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @Antilogical he uses `\d` to designate a number, I used `[0-9]`. Same functionality, matter of taste which one you use. (There probably are some differences, but for now it is enough to say they do the same)

Comment: @Antilogical, don't use `$` as it allows a `\n` at end of string. Use `\z` instead.